# Duplicate records fetched with Hibernate for Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I am working on a timesheet application built using Spring MVC 3.x using hibernate.

I have a TimeOff Class, which has a User and User Class has set of roles and a manager, manager is again a User.The page fetch size is 25 and I expect to see 25 rows of Timeoff for a user, but in case the manager has more than 1 role assigned to him, the resulting hibernate query has cross product and has duplicate rows for each role. 
The setResultTransformer brings back unique results which are less than 25 in this case. 
So my question is how do I avoid fetching any duplicates. I tried subquery with no success

The current output look like this:

```
Time Off       User    Manager  Manager Role
10-Dec-2014     A      C1         ROLE_USER
10-Dec-2014     A      C1         ROLE_MANAGER
11-Dec-2014     A      C1         ROLE_USER
11-Dec-2014     A      C1         ROLE_MANAGER
```

and so on...

```
@Entity
class TimeOff {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
  private User user;
}

@Entity
class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private User manager;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_role",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name="user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="role_id")
    )    
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MANAGER")
    public User getManager() {
        return manager;
    }
}

@Controller
class TimeOffController {
  protected DetachedCriteria getCriteria(HttpServletRequest request) {
  DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TimeOffRequest.class, "i");
  User user = getUser(request); 
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user", user));
  criteria.setResultTransformer(DetachedCriteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
  return criteria;

}
```

Thanks, Vikas